# Difference between *arr[] and **arr

Tags: c

Is the same

```
char* s1[size];
```

To

```
char** s2 = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
```

They have any difference?

Comment: Yes, if you use `sizeof` or `_Alignof` on them, or take the address `&`.

Comment: They can both be used the same, but the first has automatic storage duration, while the second does not. There are also situations in which the first can be used that the second cannot.

Comment: @Kupiakos: Nonsense, they are different types and are not the same!

Comment: Same as the difference between arr[] and *arr

Comment: @Olaf More accurately, they can be used the same in many situations.

Comment: @Kupiakos: Most exactly: no, they can not be used the same! It is just that the array is **converted** to a _pointer to the first element_ for most usages. Due to this conversion, it looks **as if** they are used the same. Note that even the index-operator `[]` does not work on an array, but only a pointer.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not saying they are the same. I'm stating they *can* used the same in many situations. The conversion to a pointer to the first element is the key here. The end result is the same for the majority of cases - they're still *used* the same by the programmer. When I use `someList[i]` with `int someList[N]`, I see an array being indexed, regardless of the details *I'm aware of*. There are many situations where the difference in type is significant - but the automatic decaying hides most of them. You say it only looks as if they're used the same - but they are being used the same.

Comment: @Kupiakos: They can not even be used in the same situations - technically. Read my comment very carrefully, then read the standard. You don't use the name of the array anymore once it has been converted to the pointer, but the pointer. This (correct) interpretation makes the whole array/pointer stuff much easier and straight-forward.

Comment: @Olaf I've read your comment. I'm normally a big pedant about this stuff. Enough to, yes, read the standard. In terms of full usage in the language, you are 100% correct. I generally prefer to not overwhelm a beginner with details that will be irrelevant for the majority of situations. In retrospect, that *is* what the question's about. That's why I left it as a comment instead of elaborating with details in an answer. Unless one is programming embedded systems where taking advantage of the full power of the language is key - operations will be simple and the decaying is irrelevant.

Comment: @Kupiakos: Your approach will eventually result in more missunderstanding. By simply learning when an array-name is converted automatically and when not, all is learned about arrays. Next step is to learn how to use pointer, no arrays involved anymore. Sound much more reasonable to me.

Comment: @Olaf And you're probably right. I likely shouldn't have mentioned how arrays can appear to be used similarly to arrays in a question dedicated to the difference. However, from helping people brand-new to programming, the details between the two are only confusing when the concept of a type itself isn't fully concrete.

Comment: @Kupiakos: Agreed there are more fundamental things to understand first. But that is true for almost all programming - there is always something more basic to know first. That is the reason every good progrmming books starts with integer types, not compound types. Anyway, this is no tutorial site and every asker here is required to know the basics at least to understand what her problem is. If that is not true (and there are many actually), they should just not try to run before they can crouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, `*arr[]` and `**arr` are different. For example :

```
char *arr[size]; //case 1
```

Here `arr` is a an array of size `size` whose elements are of the type `char*`

Whereas,

```
char **arr; //case2
```

Here `arr` is itself a pointer to the type `char*`

> **Note:** In *case 1* array `arr` degrades to a pointer to become the type `char**` but it's not possible the other way around i.e, pointer in *case 2* cannot become an array.

Answer (score -1):

There are few differences:

- `s1` is not an lvalue, so it cannot be modified (e.g. using assignment or increment operators). Because of this it resembles type `char** const s1` which also does not allow modifications (but in this case this is caused by `const` modifier).
- operator `&` used on address of array will return address of array (i.e. address of 1st element). When `&` will be used on variable, it will return its address:

  ```
  assert((void*)&s1 == (void*)s1);
  assert((void*)&s2 != (void*)s2);
  ```
- `sizeof()` used on array will return array size, while `sizeof()` used on pointer will return pointer size - usually it will be the same as `sizeof(void*)`, but C standard does not require this (see comments below):

  ```
  assert(sizeof(s1) == size * sizeof(char*));
  assert(sizeof(s1) == size * sizeof(s1[0])); // this is the same
  assert(sizeof(s2) == sizeof(void*)); // on some platforms this may fail
  ```
- and of course obvious one - `s1` is allocated on stack, `s2` on heap. Because of this `s1` will be destroyed automatically when execution leaves current scope, and `s2` requires call to `free` to release memory.

Update: here is example code which checks above asserts:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const int size = 22;

    char* s1[size];
    char** s2 = (char**)malloc(size * sizeof(char*));

    assert((void*)&s1 == (void*)s1);
    assert((void*)&s2 != (void*)s2);

    assert(sizeof(s1) == size * sizeof(char*));
    assert(sizeof(s1) == size * sizeof(s1[0])); // this is the same
    assert(sizeof(s2) == sizeof(void*)); // on some platforms this may fail

    free(s2);

    // Attempts to modify value
    char** const s3 = s1;
    ++s2; 
    //++s1; // compilation error - lvalue required as increment operand
    //++s3; // compilation error - increment of read-only variable ‘s3’

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The equality-operators in your `assert()`s for `&` are constraint violations.

Comment: That is plain wrong! An array is not a pointer is not an array.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot about casting pointers to void*. I corrected this and added example code with these assertions.

Comment: Your claim that `type *arr[]` is equivalent to `type **const ptr` is still wrong. You'll find some useful reading in C11 draft standard n1570, *6.3 Conversions, 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators*.

Comment: My bad, I read this in a book that this is the case when I learnt C++ in the past and did not try to check if this was really true. Thanks for pointing this out for me, I learnt something new :). I updated my answer for this.

Comment: Note that size of pointer to `void` is not necessarily the same as `sizeof(char **)`. The C Standard only makes such provision for pointer to `char` (N1570 6.2.5/28): `A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.`. The other pointers' types may be of whatever size: `Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.`.

Answer (score -1):

```
char* s1[size];
```

Is an array of pointers of type `char` that is allocated on the stack.

```
char** s2 = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
```

Is a pointer of type `char **` that is allocated on the stack but points to a dynamic array of pointers of type `char *` allocated on the heap.

The two differ in terms of scope and the usual difference between arrays and pointers.

Answer (score -1):

`s1` is an array, `s2` is a pointer. `s2` points to the first element of the `malloc`ed array.

The array `s1` has automatic storage duration, while the array which `s2` points to has dynamic storage duration.

Also, in C89 `char* s1[size];` is valid only if `size` is a constant expression, because C89 doesn't support variable-length arrays.